# How can I get one value from a @client.command function and implement it into another

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a dictionary initialized into a dataframe that has values inside a @client.command function for discord.py. I want to use this dataframe in the next function that I have written. I am unsure of how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose you have a command like this

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx, arg)
    await ctx.send("the variable is " +  arg)
```

you can share it by using global variable

```
argument = ""

@client.command()
async def test(ctx, arg)
    global argument
    argument = arg
    await ctx.send("the variable is " +  arg)

@client.command()
async def anothertest(ctx)
    global argument
    await ctx.send("the previous arg is " +  argument)
```

Comment: Just be aware that this variable will be *global*, i.e. the same for all servers the bot is in

Comment: yes in that case you can make it a dictionary for each server `{guild.id : "that variable"}`. It will make it guild specific then :D